# Node.JS router get returning ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE page error

Tags: sql-server, node.js, express

I'm building a node.JS app with express.js, which is basically is a bridge to processes in SQL Server.

So I have this router:

```
router.get('/runpr/:ref', function(req, res, next) {

var p1 = req.params.ref;
execSQLQuery("EXEC SP_PROCESSA_PREMIO "+p1, function(result, err) {
    var response = '';
    if ( err != null ) { 
        // change error to node errors
        response = [{
            A_STATUS: 0,
            MSG: err.originalError.info.message,
            FINISHED: new Date(Date.now())
        }];  
    } else {
        response = result.recordset;
    }

    res.json( response );
});
```

})

The called function execSQLQuery:

```
function execSQLQuery(sqlQry, callback) {
var request = new sql.Request();
request.query(sqlQry, function(err, recordset) {
    callback(recordset, err);
});
```

}

The SQL connection is working fine for other queries, but this particular PROCEDURE is called from node and it takes 3 minutes, more or less. The procedure always returns me a dataset with the SQL error or a successful outcome. But in this case, when I browse to the router, it takes some time then to return me the error ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.

When I check SQL Server, the procedure is still running, I was assuming there's a **mssql-node timeout**, so I set up:>

```
var config = {
    user: 'xxxx',
    password: 'xxx',
    server: 'xxxx',
    database: 'xxxx',
    connectionTimeout: 500000,
    requestTimeout: 500000
}
```

And also this, **for node itself**:

```
// listen and timeout
var server = app.listen(app.get('port'))
server.timeout = 500000;
```

None of them solved the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the answer. I was setting the configuration below

```
// listen and timeout
var server = app.listen(app.get('port'))
server.timeout = 500000;
```

in my app.js file, that's wrong...

Since I'm running it with express.js, you should add the following line

```
server.timeout = 500000;
```

in the 'www' file inside the bin folder.